# How to do an ajax get in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to do an ajax post in flutter ajax post

This is my code.

```
get() async {
      var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
      var httpClient = new HttpClient();

      String result;
      try {
        var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
        var response = await request.close();
        if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
          var jsonString = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
          var data = json.decode(jsonString);
          result = data;
        } else {
          result =
              'Error getting IP address:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}';
        }
      } catch (exception) {
        result = 'Failed getting IP address';
      }

      print(result);
    }
```

When I try with `https://httpbin.org/ip` it works fine.
but with `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users` it fail, I am very new to flutter and help much appreciated.

I printed out the exception it was throwing.

> ```
> type '_BoundSinkStream<dynamic, List<int>>' is not a subtype of type
> '_HttpIncoming' where
> _BoundSinkStream is from dart:async List is from dart:core int is from dart:core List is from dart:core int is from dart:core
> _HttpIncoming is from dart:_http List is from dart:core int is from dart:core
> ```

Couldn't make anything out of it.

When changing to `String result to List result = []`

```
type '_BoundSinkStream<dynamic, List<int>>' is not a subtype of type '_HttpIncoming' where
_BoundSinkStream is from dart:async
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
_HttpIncoming is from dart:_http
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
```

Updated the code with more debug info :

```
getData() async {
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    List result = [];
    try {
      print('0');
      var request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(url));
      print('1');
      var response = await request.close();
      print('2');
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
        print('3');
        var jsonString = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        print('4');
        var data = json.decode(jsonString);
        print('5');
        result = data;
        print('6');
      } else {
        // result = 'Error getting IP address:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}';
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      // result = 'Failed getting IP address';
      print('7');
      print(exception);
      print('8');
    }

    print(result);
  }
```

Exception :

```
0
1
2
3
7
type '_BoundSinkStream<dynamic, List<int>>' is not a subtype of type '_HttpIncoming' where
_BoundSinkStream is from dart:async
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
_HttpIncoming is from dart:_http
List is from dart:core
int is from dart:core
8
[]
```

Flutter Version

```
Flutter 0.1.5 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 3ea4d06340 (5 weeks ago) • 2018-02-22 11:12:39 -0800
Engine • revision ead227f118
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.28.0.flutter-0b4f01f759
```

True it was old I updated flutter

```
Flutter 0.2.3 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 5a58b36e36 (3 weeks ago) • 2018-03-13 13:20:13 -0700
Engine • revision e61bb9ac3a
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.35.flutter-290c576264
```

Now I have a new error.

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
7
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List' where
_InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
String is from dart:core
List is from dart:core
8
```

I updated the code from a [GitHub](https://github.com/bramvbilsen/Flutter-HTTP-Requests-REST-api) post

```
getData() async {
    print("0");
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    print("1");
    data = json.decode(response.body);
    print("2");
    print(data[1]["name"]);
    print("3");
    // print(response.body);
    print("end");
  }
```

And this is working.

Comment: "it fail" definitely needs more concrete information

Comment: I am very new to flutter. But my guess is json decode is failing. I tried to put some print statements

Comment: I'm using Dart since many years and have answered thousands of StackOverflow questions, but that only ever worked when people provided more information about the problem than "didn't work" ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I am extremely sorry for posting such a question. Please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: that's much better. I the error message you added really an exact copy of the error message you get? It looks scrambled to me.

Comment: found it, the formatting was wrong

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks how to get it fixed. Still pretty stuck with it.

Comment: I'll have a closer look later. Breakfast first ;-)

Comment: Sure :) Most important meal of the day

Comment: Basically @YashDoshi s answer is correct. `json.decode(jsonString)` returns a `List` and you assign that to `result` which you declared as `String` and that fails for good reason.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried the same. But still it fails. Will add the exception

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Updated the code and exception

Comment: I can't reproduce with the code you posted. What is your Flutter version `flutter --version`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer flutter version updated in the question

Comment: That's quite an outdated version. Ißd suggest `flutter uprade` `flutter doctor`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer good one mate. That was one of the issue. But I face new issue now.

Comment: With the same URL as before?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes bro :( Didn't know flutter is so hard.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I can't reproduce locally. I don't think Flutter is hard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167931/discussion-between-vinbhai4u-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the above code is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what http package you are using.

you can use this [http package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http#-readme-tab-)

and it work with the below code with both url

```
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
//var url = "https://httpbin.org/ip";
http.get(url)
    .then((response) {
  print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
  print("Response body: ${response.body}");
});
```

Comment: They are using the `dart:io` HttpClient, switching to a separate package is not solving the problem

Comment: You are right sorry i didn't notice about the result. The error is catch is type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String' where
  List is from dart:core
  String is from dart:core

So you should Declare result as List not as String

Comment: @JLouage I tried to change result as List, still its not working. Please check the exception I am getting

Comment: @JLouage Only this package worked. dart:io didn't work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To decode JSON Array you need an List of string, try changing

```
String result;
```

with

```
List result = [];
```

Comment: Why would you need a list of string?

Comment: You are decoding an JSON Array, as an result you`ll get an List. If you just want to access inner element of your array you can direcly access it using your data variable like data[0]

Comment: I see. You run the code locally and saw that the response is an array. I assumed you derived that from the information in the question. I think your answer is correct. It could perhaps provide more guidance to a complete solution. Changing `String` to `List` causes other issues because in the `else {...}` and `catch(exception) {...}` parts he tries to assign a string to `result`.